# Lagrange's Linear Equation , Method of Multipliers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

This is an solution of an partial differential equation by Lagrange method of multipliers.

My Question is as indicated by arrows we get zero at the denominator and "it's get transfered to the other side of the equation which equates the whole equation to zero."

How is this possible? (X/0) is not defined or infinity. It's doing like " x/0 = y
x = 0*y
x = 0 "        which is wrong.

[image: Click here to see the Image]

Comment: what book is it ?

Comment: I don´t see a function which has to be optimized.

Comment: @callculus not an optimisation problem I need to find general solution f(u,v)=0

Comment: @Aryadeva "advance engineering mathematics by hk dass"

Comment: @Aryadeva can you answer my question

Comment: It's a notation and abuse of notation that makes things easy with that zero at the denominator.

Comment: @Aryadeva what do you mean by "abuse of notation" which "notation" are you talking about. Please elaborate

Comment: I added an answer that gives the same answer. I mean we dont use zero at the denominator this is what I mean by abuse of notation.

Comment: @Aryadeva but the second ans don't come that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a notation. Note that you can find a constant of integration this way without the zero at the denominator:

$$\dfrac  {dx}{y+z}=\dfrac  {dy}{-(x+z)}=\dfrac  {dz}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{y+z}=\dfrac  {d(y+z)}{-(y+z)}$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{1}=\dfrac  {d(y+z)}{-1}$$
$$dx=-d(y+z)$$
$$x+y+z=c_1$$
it gives the same result.

For th second constant of integration
$$\dfrac  {dx}{y+z}=\dfrac  {dy}{-(x+z)}=\dfrac  {dz}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac  {xdx}{xy+xz}=\dfrac  {ydy}{-(yx+zy)}=\dfrac  {dz}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac  {xdx+ydy}{xz-zy}=\dfrac  {dz}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac  {xdx+ydy}{z}=\dfrac  {dz}{1}$$
$$xdx+ydy=zdz$$
Integration gives:
$$x^2+y^2=z^2+c_2$$

Comment: but the second answer don't come that way

Comment: Thanks!                                                                But don't you think the method given in book is not valid. According to basic algebraic rules

Comment: One more question does it have only two solution or infinitely many solutions

Comment: Great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @HimanshuKothekar